# Add utc time to filename python

Tags: python, string, datetime

How can i get the current time in UTC time (Zulu style for hours and minutes: 0100Z)  , and add it to a string so i can concatenate it

This gives me cannot concatenate string:

```
import datetime
utc_datetime = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
utc_datetime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H%MZ") //Result: '2011-12-12-0939Z'
filename = '/SomeDirectory/AnotherDirectory/FilePrefix_'+utc_datetime+'.txt'
```

And this  gives me another string for the filename:

//returns: /SomeDirectory/AnotherDirectory/FilePrefix_2011-12-12 09:42:15.374022.txt

```
import datetime
utc_datetime = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
utc_datetime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H%MZ") //Result: '2011-12-12-0939Z'
filename = '/SomeDirectory/AnotherDirectory/FilePrefix_'+str(utc_datetime)+'.txt'
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you want to do is probably :

```
import datetime
utc_datetime = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
formated_string = utc_datetime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H%MZ") //Result: '2011-12-12-0939Z'
filename = '/SomeDirectory/AnotherDirectory/FilePrefix_%s.txt'% formated_string
```

or in a one-liner way :

```
filename = '/SomeDirectory/AnotherDirectory/FilePrefix_%s.txt'%datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H%MZ")
```

When using [datetime.strftime](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime) it returns the string formatted as you need, it does not modify the datetime object.

EDIT : use `%s` instead of `+`, thanks Danilo Bargen

Comment: You shouldn't use `+` to concatenate several strings because of performance reasons. Use `filename = '/directory/prefix_%s.txt' % datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H%MZ")` instead.

Answer (score 1):

The `strftime` method of a datetime object only returns a value, but doesn't manipulate the original object. You need to save the result into the variable itself, or into a new variable.

```
import datetime
utc_datetime = datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H%MZ")
utc_datetime //Result: '2011-12-12-0939Z'
```

Additionally, you shouldn't use `+` to concatenate several strings because of [performance reasons](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips#String_Concatenation). Use this instead:

```
filename = '/directory/prefix_%s.txt' % utc_datetime
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the result of `utc_datetime.strftime()` into a variable:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> utc_datetime = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
>>> s=utc_datetime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H%MZ")
>>> filename = '/SomeDirectory/AnotherDirectory/FilePrefix_' + s + '.txt'
>>> print filename
/SomeDirectory/AnotherDirectory/FilePrefix_2011-12-12-0946Z.txt
>>>
```

You're currently computing a value and throwing away the string result.